# exe файл, полученный с помощью pyinstaller запускается в командной строке, но не запускается двойным нажатием ЛКМ

Tags: pyqt5, gui, pyqt, exe, pyinstaller

Визуальная часть сделана с помощью pyqt5, переведена в exe с помощью pyinstaller, все работает в консоли, но не работает из папки (видно, что файл быстро открывает и также быстро закрывается).Программа работает исправно, никаких ошибок не выдает! прочитал, что можно добавить input() в конец программы, добавил, не помогло.
Подскажите в какую часть программного кода я должен вставить input()? или как в целом запустить программу не из консоли, а просто двойным нажатием ЛКМ?
Привожу фото для лучшего понимания проблемы, некоторые части замазал фиолетовым, т.к там пока что бред написан. И саму программу укоротил (чересчур большая выходит).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вот код основной программы**

```
import PyQt5
import sklearn
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from пьянка1 import Ui_MainWindow
from пьянка2 import Ui_Form1
from пьянка3 import Ui_Form2
from пьянка4 import Ui_Form3
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math as m
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor
import sys

class Widget1(QtWidgets.QWidget,Ui_Form1):
#Здесь есть какой-то код....

class Widget2(QtWidgets.QWidget,Ui_Form2):
#Здесь есть какой-то код....

class Widget3(QtWidgets.QWidget,Ui_Form3):
#Здесь есть какой-то код....

class Start_Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow,Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Start_Window, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.hide_widget_1)

        self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.hide_widget_2)
    def hide_widget_1(self):
        self.frame.hide()
        self.widget = (Widget1(self))
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.widget)

    def hide_widget_2(self):
        self.frame.hide()
        self.widget = (Widget2(self))
        self.verticalLayout_3.addWidget(self.widget)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = Start_Window()
application.show()
app.setStyle('Fusion')
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Друзья, это называется сам пошутил - сам посмеялся)
Короче проблема была в том, что моя прога ссылалась на Exel файл, который не учитывался при компиляции программы в exe. Как я это понял? при запуске программы двойным нажатием ЛКМ на долю секунды открывалась и закрывалась консоль и в ней что-то было написано. Ничего лучше, как снять на замедленную съемку и посмотреть ошибку - я не придумал. В итоге была ошибка типа: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'name.xlsx'.` Добавил данный файл при компиляции и все заработало!
Странно только одно, что при запуске из консоли, программа работала нормально, хотя вроде тоже ссылалась на Exel файл.
Всем спасибо!